# How to validate 3 related drop down lists in ASP

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, validation

Is there a way to validate a 3 dropdown lists as a group? as they are for a date.
So one dropdown is for the Date, one for the Month, one for the Year.

I need to validate them so no one under 18 can access the site.

```
 <asp:Label ID="LabelDOB" CssClass="labels" runat="server" Text="Date of Birth: "></asp:Label>
                    <br />
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="DateList" CssClass="marginset" Width="80px"   runat="server">
 </asp:DropDownList>

 <asp:Label ID="LabelDOB" CssClass="labels" runat="server" Text="Date of Birth: "></asp:Label>
                    <br />
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="MonthList" CssClass="marginset" Width="80px"   runat="server">
 </asp:DropDownList>

 <asp:Label ID="LabelDOB" CssClass="labels" runat="server" Text="Date of Birth: "></asp:Label>
                    <br />
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="YearList" CssClass="marginset" Width="80px"   runat="server">
 </asp:DropDownList>
```

Comment: Why not use a date picker? If not, create a date in JS and test that the year, month and date are the same as the entered

Comment: it doesnt actually specify in my assignment spec so im guessing it doesnt matter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a datepicker, it will handle validation and it'll already be formatted correctly.

But if you wanted to use the 3 dropdowns, grab the text values from all dropdowns, concatenating them into a string variable, then format that string as a date.

Comment: xD I Knew I had to hurry for this question.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you combine the selected values of the Drop Down Lists into a string and then convert them into a DateTime variable. Check if this is earlier or equal to DateTime.Now.Year - 18, then take the appropriate action based off the result.